# JBoss AS 7.1 Server Level Redirect

Tags: redirect, jboss7.x

We moved (or renamed) our webapplication from `http://domain.tld/webapp/...` to `http://domain.tld/ourWebapp/...`

Now we want to redirect old urls to the new one - Most redirect solutions are handled inside the application. This however won't work, because with the wrong war-name given, the webapp is not triggered at all.

Is there a way to add redirects on the - let's say - server level, instead of handling it from within the application? (We don't want to deploy a "redirect application" listening on the old war-name.)

I found this documentation: http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/modules/rewrite.html but it seems outdated, as it still talkes about `server.xml` (there is none in JBOSS AS 7.1). All the mentioned elements aren't there either and not supported it seems...

---

After a lot of testing, I figured out, that this is possible INSIDE the standalone.xml, right in the virtual-server subsystem. However, there are still some Issues:

**Whats working so far**: The following entry leads to a forward as expected:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
   <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
      <alias name="localhost"/>
      <rewrite pattern="^/webapp/(.*?)$" substitution="/myWebapp/$1" flags="R=301,L">

      </rewrite>
   </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

The (outdated) docu for doing rewrites with jboss (http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/modules/rewrite.html) states, that there are several environmnet variables that can be used.

I noticed, that the `${HTTP_}` Variables are working, but using anything else gives me a 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'.

What I tried (and need to achieve):

```
<rewrite pattern="^/webapp/(.*?)$" substitution="${SERVER_PROTOCOL}://${SERVER_ADDR}:${SERVER_PORT}/myWebapp/$1" flags="R=301,L">
```

So basically a redirect that works independent of protocol and/or hostname.

I tried it with a "relative" Redirect (`substitution="/myWebapp/$1"`) - This worked, but does **not** keep the port (requests on `http://ip:8080/webapp/` are forwarded to `http://ip/myWebapp/`)

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
   <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
      <alias name="localhost"/>
      <rewrite pattern="^/webapp/(.*?)$" substitution="/myWebapp/$1" flags="R=301,L">

      </rewrite>
   </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

is working as expected and keeping the port. (Dunno, why it did not work on the first try, maybe didnt restart the server properly, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

There's some explanation & examples here as well, if you have access to the RedHat site:

https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/189423

---

JBoss EAP6 provided Global Rewrite valve which can be enabled in the "web" subsystem of your configuration as following:
For redirecting all http requests coming for localhost:8080/MXBeanDemo should be redirected to "www.yahoo.com/"

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
            <rewrite pattern="^/MXBeanDemo(.*)" substitution="http://www.yahoo.com" flags="R"/>   <!-- NOTICE -->
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

For redirecting localhost:8080/Abcd to  localhost:8080/Wxyz

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
            <rewrite pattern="^/Abcd(.*)" substitution="/Wxyz" flags="R"/>   <!-- NOTICE -->
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```